# PANDAS: How do a copy a value in pandas from a dataframe to another dataframe based on different cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1

| Ship_Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 07/15/2014 | 5 |
| 08/19/2015 | 9 |
| 09/20/2016 | 7 |

I also have df2

| Ship_Date |
| --- |
| 08/19/2015 |
| 07/15/2014 |
| 09/20/2016 |
| 07/15/2014 |

I need the final output for df2 to be

| Ship_Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 08/19/2015 | 9 |
| 07/15/2014 | 5 |
| 09/20/2016 | 7 |
| 07/15/2014 | 5 |

I also already added the 'Price' Column for df2. I need help setting the values in each cell for the 'Price' column to be the price corresponding to the date in df1

Comment: `df2 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='Ship_Date')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple of ways.

merging the 2 dataframes on "Ship_Date"

```
new_df = df2.merge(df1, on="Ship_Date", how="left")

print(new_df)
    Ship_Date  Price
0  08/19/2015      9
1  07/15/2014      5
2  07/15/2014      5
3  09/20/2016      7
```

---

Using the `map` function to create a new column:

```
date_mappings = df1.set_index("Ship_Date")["Price"]
df2["Price"] = df2["Ship_Date"].map(date_mappings)

print(df2)
    Ship_Date  Price
0  08/19/2015      9
1  07/15/2014      5
2  09/20/2016      7
3  07/15/2014      5
```

---

Temporarily set df1.index to be "Ship_Date", then reindexing df1 so it takes the same shape as df2:

```
new_df = df1.set_index("Ship_Date").reindex(df2["Ship_Date"]).reset_index()

print(new_df)
    Ship_Date  Price
0  08/19/2015      9
1  07/15/2014      5
2  09/20/2016      7
3  07/15/2014      5
```

Comment: If I use merge, won't it leave null data? For example, I have two 07/15/2014 in df2 but only one 07/15/2014 in df1.

Comment: It will simply repeat the data from `df1` (as shown in the output from the answer)- however if you have a date in `df1` that is not in `df2` this when you will generate nulls. If this is the case (or to be more cautious in general), you should use `df2.merge(df1, on="Ship_Date", how="left")` to ensure that you only output Ship_Dates that exist in df2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **map** function for the pandas series:

Map the df2['Ship_Date'] to the values of df1['Price'], and store the mapped series in your 'Price' column of the df2. The **mapping argument** has to be a pandas series with the index 'Ship_Date'.It can be done by setting the df1 index to the '*Ship_Date*' and selecting the '*Price*' column.

`df2['Price'] = df2['Ship_Date'].map(df1.set_index('Ship_Date')['Price'])`